# Why the we use the infinite loop for the socket server to keep listening?

Tags: sockets, server, serversocket

Everywhere on the internet when it comes to keep listening for the incoming socket connection the server needs to run the infinite loop. Why we use the infinite loop for the socket server to keep listening?

**For example:**

```
while (true) {
    accept a connection;
    create a thread to deal with the client;
}
```

This is 21st century and everything is technology, so, is there any other approach instead of infinite loop. Don't we think that the infinite loop will wast the CPU cycles and will add extra load on the server. Are chat apps like WhatsApp, Messenger, Viber etc servers also runs the infinite loop approach?

I hope real geeks will answer instead of down voting my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all of the examples you see like this, the "accept a connection" line is a blocking call.  Because of that, you aren't wasting CPU cycles.  Your code is stopped until a new connection is made.  Then it creates the handling thread and starts waiting again.